# How do I make box padding display on top of the underlying image with overflow: hidden?

Tags: html, css

I have a box with padding and border. The image is sometimes too large to fit. I'd like to display the box without distorting the image (crop is fine) and keep the padding and border (matte). Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/n236vh2u/

Notice the bottom padding is overwritten by the image? I tried setting `z-index: 2;` on the outer `<a>` box, setting `box-sizing: padding-box;`, setting two borders `border: 5px solid white, 1px solid #ccc;`, but none of those worked.

Comment: I may have solved it with a 3rd inner `div` shim. http://jsfiddle.net/n236vh2u/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the clip property on the image.

```
#gallerysingle img {
    text-align:justify;
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px, 100px, 100px, 0px);
}
```

Note, that it has to be positioned absolute for doing so. Therefore you will have to set the height of the a tag fixed to 100px.

```
#gallerysingle a {
    overflow:hidden;
    display: inline-block; 
    max-height: 100px; 
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 11.2px 11px 0px;
    padding:5px;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[See it in action – jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4c92sorn/)

**Update**

To answer the question of browser support for this property, i did some more research:

Being a CSS 2.1 property, clip browser support appears to be fairly good. [This MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/clip#Browser_Compatibility) says it is working in all major browsers since way back.

I've also done some testing on mobile showing it works with android 4.1 stock browser and mobile firefox as well as ipad 1 safari.

Also note, that this property is deprecated. MDN suggest to use clip-path instead. But apparently browser support for clip-path is not sufficient yet. So i would stick to clip for now until clip-path is widely supported. The syntax for clip-path appears to be the same, just exchange the property name.

Comment: Thanks! I actually like my answer and Chris' answer conceptually, but the HTML is generated inside a PHP function in a library, so this is much easier to modify, and less generated HTML too! I'm just worried clip won't be supported on mobile or an odd browser.

Answer (score 2):

Split up your styles over both the div and the a:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n236vh2u/4/)

CSS:

```
#gallerysingle {
    max-height: 100px; 
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 11.2px 11px 0px;
    padding:5px;
    width:100px;
}

#gallerysingle a {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#gallerysingle img {text-align:justify;}
```

Comment: Oh, #gallerysingle actually contains multiple image thumbnails. It can have multiple rows and height > 100. But I think I see what you are getting at.

Comment: Yeah, the point is wrap your anchor tags in another div and apply the styles there. :D